# Row rendering on extendedDataTable doesnt work

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, richfaces, row

**Question (short version)**

I have an issue with richfaces(4.3.2-final).
I'm trying to rerender a row/cells inside a rich:extendedDataTable. I can't get it to work.
The only thing that works is to rerender the whole table.

All examples/tutorials i can find are for version 3.3. Those solutions dont work for me.

I hope you can help me with a solution or a 4.2+ example/tutorial.

---

**Long version of the question**

[image: extendedDataTable]
**Not selected row cells:**

```
<a4j:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{inactive}">
    <h:outputText 
       value="#{cc.attrs.rowItem.getValue(cc.attrs.id)}"
       styleClass="outputField"
       style="#{cc.attrs.style}">
     </h:outputText>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

**Selected Row cells:**

```
<a4j:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{active and field.echoed}">
<h:inputText
    value="#{field.value}" 
    id="#{cc.attrs.id}ID"
    disabled="#{field.disabled}"
    readonly="#{field.readonly}"
    rendered="true"
    title="#{field.title}"/>
    ....
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

**On selection of other rows:**

```
<a4j:ajax event="selectionchange" 
          listener="#{crudBean.actionForm.selectionListener}" 
      render="messages,saveButton,deleteButton,multiOccurenceTable"
/>
```

**HTML code, not selected row cell:**

```
<td class="rf-edt-td-j_idt230">
  <div class="rf-edt-c rf-edt-c-j_idt230">
    <div class="rf-edt-c-cnt">
      <div id="multiOccurenceTable:0:soort:soort">
        <div id="multiOccurenceTable:0:soort:j_idt140">
          <span class=" outputField" style="">VO</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

**Selected row cell HTML:**

```
<td class="rf-edt-td-j_idt230">
  <div class="rf-edt-c rf-edt-c-j_idt230">
     <div class="rf-edt-c-cnt">
       <div id="multiOccurenceTable:1:soort:soort">
         <div id="multiOccurenceTable:1:soort:j_idt240">
           <input id="multiOccurenceTable:1:soort:soortID" name="multiOccurenceTable:1:soort:soortID" value="VO" type="text">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

**My attempts:**
The on selectionchange rerender is now put on the table:"multiOccurenceTable".
This works, on every selection change the whole table gets rerendered.

For performance i try to update the table on row or cell level. I can't get get this to work. I tried simple and more complex solutions, none worked. What am i doing wrong? 
(most examples/tutorials are for richfaces 3.3 on the internet which could be a reason)

Try 1, manually updating the rows/cells:

**all 3 rows**: nothing happened when i pressed the 'save' button

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{crudBean.actionForm.save}"
     render="multiOccurenceTable:0,multiOccurenceTable:1,multiOccurenceTable:2"
     reRender="multiOccurenceTable:0,multiOccurenceTable:1,multiOccurenceTable:2">Save
</a4j:commandLink>
```

**One cell**: nothing happened when i pressed the 'save1' button

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{crudBean.actionForm.save}"
     render="multiOccurenceTable:@rows(crudBean.actionForm.rowsToUpdate):soort"
     reRender="multiOccurenceTable:@rows(crudBean.actionForm.rowsToUpdate):soort">Save1
</a4j:commandLink>
```

I've also tried with **ajaxKeys** with no succes according to this [tutorial rich 3.x](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingtheajaxKeysattributeforrichdataList) and this [example (rich 3.3)](http://java.dzone.com/articles/an-introduction-to-jboss-richf?page=0,5)

If you got any possible solutions, please let me know.

---

My error is fixed. The error was not the rendering. but that the condition for rendering was set outside the component that was rendered. This resulted in rerendering the component with not updated values, which led to no change on the screen.

Lessons learned: If you have render conditions make sure the condition values are inside the rerendered component.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with richfaces 4 to know the details of the extendedDatatable. A quick search led me to believe that it is **not** possible to automagically render a row since a row isn't a component.

So you seems to be stuck having to render the individual cells.

Rendering works based on the clientId's of the components. You can find the exact ID's in your html code. Because it works on those clientId's the component you want to render already needs to be rendered.

In other words, you need to wrap your components with a panel that has an id and is rendered per default:

```
<h:outputPanel layout="block" id="soortPanel">
    <h:outputText 
       value="#{cc.attrs.rowItem.getValue(cc.attrs.id)}"
       rendered="#{inactive}">
    </h:outputText>
    <h:inputText
       value="#{field.value}" 
       rendered="#{active}"/>
</h:outputPanel>
```

The outputpanel should get an id like: **multiOccurenceTable:1:soortPanel** and you should be able to render that id.

Comment: p.s. you need to use the term render. reRender is an a4j term from earlier versions of a4j. JSF 2 basically standardized a4j and renamed reRender to render.

I think the reRender term is the better one, because you can't render anything taht isn't already rendered.

Primefaces has the best term for this; "update", but that doesn't really help clear the confusion :)

Comment: Thanks. The error was somewhere else, this answer made me look in the right direction.

Comment: ps. for the correction for future readers: <h:outputPanel> should be <a4j:outputPanel>.